Trying to create a new proxy for an AWS postgresql proxy that has yet to be created with terraform. I am using data blocks but that fails during plan?
I am trying to create a new proxy dynamically for each cluster that gets created through module aurora_cluster{}. We then call a module to create a cluster secret. Therefore, modules that have been created are easily available to pick up terraform infrastructure for RDS proxy, but say we add a new cluster key, it keeps failing, because we are using data blocks. How do I get around that?
I have tried using data blocks, I have tried using triggers. I know I need to expand more on graphs and dependencies but I feel like I have and still can’t figure out what needs to be created first.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look here first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
